# Are there like "asyncio.gather()" to run multiple threads or processes together in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

There are 2 sets of code below to run multiple threads or multiple processes.

#### Multiple threads:

```py
from threading import Thread
import queue

def test1(num1, num2, q):
    q.put(num1 + num2)

def test2(num1, num2, q):
    q.put(num1 + num2)

queue1 = queue.Queue()
queue2 = queue.Queue()

thread1 = Thread(target=test1, args=(2, 3, queue1))
thread2 = Thread(target=test2, args=(4, 5, queue2))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print(queue1.get()) # 5
print(queue2.get()) # 9
```

#### Multiple processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def test1(num1, num2, q):
    q.put(num1 + num2)

def test2(num1, num2, q):
    q.put(num1 + num2)

queue1 = Queue()
queue2 = Queue()

process1 = Process(target=test1, args=(2, 3, queue1))
process2 = Process(target=test2, args=(4, 5, queue2))
process1.start()
process2.start()
process1.join()
process2.join()

print(queue1.get()) # 5
print(queue2.get()) # 9
```

And, the code below can run multiple `async` tasks together:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

async def test2(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
                                                  # Here
result1, result2 = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(test1(2, 3), test2(4, 5)))  
print(result1) # 5
print(result2) # 9
```

Now, I wonder if there are the functions like `asyncio.gather()` above to run multiple threads or processes together as shown below:

#### Multiple threads:

```py
from threading import Thread
import queue

def test1(num1, num2):
    q.put(num1 + num2)

def test2(num1, num2):
    q.put(num1 + num2)
                         # Here
result1, result2 = Thread.gather(test1(2, 3), test2(4, 5))
print(result1) # 5
print(result2) # 9
```

#### Multiple processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def test1(num1, num2):
    q.put(num1 + num2)

def test2(num1, num2):
    q.put(num1 + num2)
                          # Here
result1, result2 = Process.gather(test1(2, 3), test2(4, 5))
print(result1) # 5
print(result2) # 9
```

So, are there like `asyncio.gather()` to run multiple threads or processes together in Python?

Comment: No.  You can certainly store your threads/processes in a list and do `for t in threadlist:` / `t.join()`.  You don't need to wait for the `join` to fetch from the queue -- you can read the results as soon as they are produced, and join only later.

Answer (score -1):

That's why the `concurrent.futures` module exists.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
import asyncio

def print_hi():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("hi")
    return 1

async def print_hi_async():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("hi")
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    threadpool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    processpool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    future1 = loop.run_in_executor(threadpool, print_hi)
    future2 = loop.run_in_executor(processpool, print_hi)
    future3 = loop.create_task(print_hi_async())
    coroutine = print_hi_async()
    # Here
    result1, result2, result3, result4 = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(future1, future2, future3, coroutine))
    print(result1, result2, result3, result4)
```